# Juju ( a DevOps tool) installation on Ubuntu via VMWare

Tags: juju

I have installed VMWare for using Ubuntu . Now I want to install Juju tool in Ubuntu , how can I install it ?

Comment: Check this [link](https://oxyme.wordpress.com/2018/08/30/ubuntu-18-04-lts-juju-server-part-2-8/)

Comment: Do you mean that you're running an Ubuntu virtual machine inside of VMware Workstation? Or do you have a vSphere available that you would like to add as a private cloud?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways of installing Juju, via SNAP or via PPA repository

Via snap

```
sudo snap install juju --classic
```

Via repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository -yu ppa:juju/stable
sudo apt install juju
```

You can find a reference here [official juju documentation](https://jaas.ai/docs/installing)